# How to create PDF with anchor tag using DOMPDF

Tags: php, dom, pdf-generation, anchor, dompdf

I am trying to include anchor tag in my pdf which is creating using DOM PDF library. Below is the code

```
$html = ob_get_clean();     
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style> *{margin:0;padding:0} </style></head>
<body style="font-family: Helvetica; background:#fff; width:692pt; height:712pt;">';
$html .= '<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Click for Google</a>';
$html .= '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper('letter', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
```

Link is showing in the generated pdf. But when I click on it, nothing is happening. I want to open the link in browser. Any suggestions?

Comment: DOM PDF default take anchor tag. you can look into example http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php#css_position_fixed.html,pdf

Comment: Yes. But what is wrong in my code. why it is not working?

Comment: What version of dompdf? What PDF viewer? I'm seeing similar behavior when the PDF is in an iframe. Could be a bug or viewer compatibility issue. You may want to submit a bug report: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/new

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
<script type="text/php">
$html = ob_get_clean();     
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style> *{margin:0;padding:0} </style></head>
<body style="font-family: Helvetica; background:#fff; width:692pt; height:712pt;">';
$html .= '<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Click for Google</a>';
$html .= '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper('letter', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();

</script>
```